# Variables in Kotlin, differences with Java: 'var' vs. 'val'?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to learn [Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language)). What is  `val`, `var` and `internal` in Kotlin compared to Java?

In Java:

```
 RadioGroup radioGroup;
 RadioButton button;
 Button submit;
```

After converting it shows:

```
 internal var radioGroup: RadioGroup
 internal var button: RadioButton
 internal var submit: Button
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`val` and `var` are the two keywords you can use to declare variables (and properties). The difference is that using `val` gives you a read-only variable, which is the same as using the `final` keyword in Java.

```
var x = 10    // int x = 10;
val y = 25    // final int y = 25;
```

Using `val` whenever you can is the convention in Kotlin, and you should only make something a `var` if you know that you'll be changing its value somewhere.

See the official documentation about [defining local variables](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#defining-local-variables) and [declaring properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#declaring-properties).

---

`internal` is a visibility modifier that doesn't exist in Java. It marks a member of a class that will only be visible within the module it's in. This is a similar visibility to what the default `package` visibility gives you in Java (which is why the converter would use it when converting members with `package` visibility). However, it's not exactly the same. Also, note that it's not the default visibility in Kotlin, classes and their members in Kotlin are `public` by default.

There is more in the documentation about [visiblity modifiers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#visibility-modifiers).

Comment: just to add little, Kotlin community recommends immutability unless you have good reason to use mutable variable. No need to keep track of state of immutable variable.

Comment: `val` is more like a `final` modifier.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that a val object with var fields can be still modified in its var field -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/44200189/2436175

At least for me, coming from C++ and `const`, it was very surprising

Answer (score 14):

`val` : immutable data variable

`var` : mutable data variable

When you converted your Java code to Kotlin:

1. A converter found that you have not initialised variables, so it made them `var`(mutable) as you will initialise them later.
2. Probably your variables are unused, so the converter made them internal, guessing you will not use them outside of your package.

For more information on `var` and `var` read [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#declaring-properties), and for `internal` read [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#packages).

Answer (score 1):

***val*** use to declare final variable. Characteristics of ***val*** variables

1. Must be initialized
2. value can not be changed or reassign

[image]

***var*** is as a general variable

3. We can initialize later by using lateinit modifier

   [`lateinit` also use for global variable we can not use it for local variable]
4. value can be changed or reassign but not in global scope

[image]

***val*** in kotlin is like final keyword in java