# What is the difference between var and val in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, variables

What is the difference between `var` and `val` in Kotlin?

I have gone through this link:

[KotlinLang: Properties and Fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html)

As stated on this link:

> The full syntax of a read-only property declaration differs from a
> mutable one in two ways: it starts with val instead of var and does
> not allow a setter.

But just before there is an example which uses a setter.

```
fun copyAddress(address: Address): Address {
    val result = Address() // there's no 'new' keyword in Kotlin
    result.name = address.name // accessors are called
    result.street = address.street
    // ...
    return result
}
```

What is the exact difference between `var` and `val`?

Why do we need both?

This is **not a duplicate** of [Variables in Kotlin, differences with Java: 'var' vs. 'val'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178127/variables-in-kotlin-differences-with-java-var-vs-val) as I am asking about the doubt related to the particular example in the documentation and not just in general.

Comment: `result` can not be changed to refer to a different instance of `Address`, but the instance it refers to can still be modified. The same would be true in Java if you had a `final Address result = new Address();`

Comment: refer this http://android-kotlin-beginners.blogspot.in/2018/02/the-var-val-of-kotlin.html

Comment: Came here for the answer because the Kotlin website that first describes variables was too dumb to mention it there: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html

Answer (score 341, accepted):

In your code `result` is not changing, its `var` properties are changing. Refer comments below:

```
fun copyAddress(address: Address): Address {
    val result = Address() // result is read only
    result.name = address.name // but not their properties.
    result.street = address.street
    // ...
    return result
}
```

`val` is same as the `final` modifier in java. As you should probably know that we can not assign to a `final` variable again but can change its properties.

Comment: val and var in function and classes or in primary constructor have different meaning?

Comment: @Nothing No, everywhere its same.

Comment: But when I declare variable with var in the class it required initialization because of it declare the property. But in the function it not required initialization why?

Comment: Because when class loads into the memory, its properties also gets evaluated. But in function variables are evaluated when function code is executed.

Comment: I am confused by custom getters, example: `val size get() = someList.size` then the value of the val property changes. How is this reconciled with all the answers to this question?

Comment: @Adam its same as creating a final variable and in getter return something else.

Comment: maybe a bit, but say in java you would never create the final variable to begin with, you would just write the getter. Why would kotlin allow you to do this on ```val```why not use something else like some construction with ```var``` instead

Comment: but how come both var and val works with the iterators? like both  val iterator = collection.iterator() and  var iterator = collection.iterator() both are correct ! Here iterator is not changing but its next is changing.Any comments?

Comment: This answer is only correct for local variables, not properties. A `val` property might be mutable if it has a custom-getter, and it might be non-final, if it's marked open (final has a different meaning for local variables and for member properties).

Comment: So `val` is basically just a const variable?

Answer (score 200):

Both `val` and `var` are used to declare variables.

- `var` is like ***general*** variable and it's known as a *mutable* variable in **Kotlin** and can be assigned multiple times.
- `val` is like ***final*** variable and it's known as *immutable* in **Kotlin** and can be initialized only single time.

For more information what is `val` and `var` please see the below link:

> http://blog.danlew.net/2017/05/30/mutable-vals-in-kotlin/

Answer (score 30):

variables defined with **var are mutable(Read and Write)**

variables defined with **val are immutable(Read only)**

Kotlin can remove findViewById and reduce code for setOnClickListener in android studio. For full reference: ***[Kotlin awesome features](https://demonuts.com/kotlin-findviewbyid/)***

value of mutable variables can be changed at anytime, while you can not change value of immutable variables.

***where should I use var and where val ?***

use var where value is changing frequently. For example while getting location of android device

```
var integerVariable : Int? = null
```

use val where there is no change in value in whole class. For example you want set textview or button's text programmatically.

```
val stringVariables : String = "Button's Constant or final Text"
```

Comment: "Kotlin can remove findViewById and reduce code for setOnClickListener in android studio. For full reference: Kotlin awesome features" How is this relevant to the question asked?

Comment: val variables are not necessarily immutable.  They are final -- only the reference is immutable -- but if the object stored in the val is mutable, the object is mutable regardless of whether it is assigned via val or var.

Comment: i don't see the point of introducing two new keywords while it could be done much better understandably previously in Java

Answer (score 21):

`val` use to declare final variable. Characteristics of `val` variables

1. Must be initialized
2. value can not be changed or reassign 
   [image]

`var` is as a general variable

1. We can initialize later by using `lateinit` modifier

   [`lateinit` also use for global variable
    we can not use it for local variable]
2. value can be changed or reassign but not in global scope

[image]

`val` in `kotlin` is like  `final` keyword in  `java`

Answer (score 18):

val is **`immutable`** and var is **`mutable`** in Kotlin.

Comment: Retread of https://stackoverflow.com/a/44260269

Answer (score 15):

You can easily think it as:

`var` is used for setter (value will change).

`val` is used for getter (read-only, value won't change).

Answer (score 15):

Simply, 
var (mutable) and val (immutable values like in Java (final modifier))

```
var x:Int=3
x *= x

//gives compilation error (val cannot be re-assigned)
val y: Int = 6
y*=y
```

Answer (score 15):

```
+----------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+
|                |             val             |            var            |
+----------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+
| Reference type | Immutable(once initialized  | Mutable(can able to change|
|                | can't be reassigned)        | value)                    |
+----------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+
| Example        | val n = 20                  | var n = 20                |
+----------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+
| In Java        | final int n = 20;           | int n = 20;               |
+----------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+
```

[Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRwDWnw6RVk)

Answer (score 14):

Comparing `val` to a final is wrong!

`var`s are **mutable** `val`s are **read only**; Yes val cannot be reassigned just like final variables from Java but they can return a different value over time, so saying that they are immutable is kind of wrong;

Consider the following

```kotlin
var a = 10
a = 11 //Works as expected
```

```kotlin
val b = 10
b = 11 //Cannot Reassign, as expected
```

So far so Good!

Now consider the following for `val`s

```kotlin
val d
  get() = System.currentTimeMillis()

println(d)
//Wait a millisecond
println(d) //Surprise!, the value of d will be different both times
```

Hence, vars can correspond to nonfinal variables from Java, but val aren't exactly final variables either;

Although there are `const` in kotlin which can be like `final`, as they are compile time constants and don't have a custom getter, but they only work on primitives

Comment: Interesting example. I never thought of using a `val` in this way: since I try to use Kotlin as immutably as possible, it never occurred to me to even try using a stateful getter for a property marked `val`.

Answer (score 13):

If we declare variable using `val` then it will be **read-only** variable. We cannot change it's value. It's like **final** variable of **Java**. It's `immutable`.

But if we declare variable using `var` then it will be a variable which we can **read** or **write**. We can change it's value. It's `mutable`.

```
data class Name(val firstName: String, var lastName: String)

fun printName(name: Name): Name {
    val myName = Name("Avijit", "Karmakar") // myName variable is read only
    // firstName variable is read-only. 
    //You will get a compile time error. Val cannot be reassigned.
    myName.firstName = myName.firstName
    // lastName variable can be read and write as it's a var.
    myName.lastName = myName.lastName
    return myName
}
```

`val` cannot be initialized lately by the keyword `lateinit` but non-primitive `var` can be initialized lately by the keyword `lateinit`.

Answer (score 13):

Basically

- `var` = **variable**, so it can change
- `val` = **value**, so it can not change.

Answer (score 11):

In Kotlin **`val`** is a **read-only** property and it can be accessed by a getter only. **`val`** is immutable.

#### `val` example :

```
val piNumber: Double = 3.1415926
    get() = field
```

However, **`var`** is a **read-and-write** property, so it can be accessed not only by a getter but a setter as well. **`var`** is mutable.

#### `var` example :

```
var gravity: Double = 9.8
    get() = field
    set(value) { 
        field = value 
    }
```

#### If you try to change an immutable `val`, IDE raises an error :

```
fun main() {    
    piNumber = 3.14          // ERROR
    println(piNumber)
}

// RESULT:   Val cannot be reassigned
```

#### But a mutable `var` can be changed :

```
fun main() {    
    gravity = 0.0
    println(gravity)
}

// RESULT:   0.0
```

Answer (score 7):

**var** is like a general variable and can be assigned multiple times and is known as the mutable variable in Kotlin. Whereas **val** is a constant variable and can not be assigned multiple times and can be Initialized only single time and is known as the immutable variable in Kotlin.

**Val:**
Assigned once (Read only)

**Var:**
Mutable

example :
define a variable to store userId value:

```
val userId = 1
```

if we are trying to change the variable userId you will get Error message

```
userId = 2
error: val cannot be reassigned // Error message!
```

Let’s create a new variable to store the name of the user:

```
var userName = "Nav"
```

if you want to reassign the value of userName you can easily do this because var is mutable

```
userName = "Van"
```

and now the value of userName is "Van".

For more information visit this:
https://medium.com/techmacademy/kotlin-101-val-vs-var-behind-the-scenes-65d96c6608bf

Comment: constant variable is an oxymoron. "read-only" or "immutable" are better words to describe val

Answer (score 6):

**Value to `val` variable can be assigned only once.**

```
val address = Address("Bangalore","India")
address = Address("Delhi","India") // Error, Reassigning is not possible with val
```

Though you can't reassign the value but you can certainly modify the properties of the object.

```
//Given that city and country are not val
address.setCity("Delhi") 
address.setCountry("India")
```

That means you can't change the object reference to which the variable is pointing but the underlying properties of that variable can be changed.

**Value to var variable can be reassigned as many times as you want.**

```
var address = Address("Bangalore","India")
address = Address("Delhi","India") // No Error , Reassigning possible.
```

Obviously, It's underlying properties can be changed as long as they are not declared val.

```
//Given that city and country are not val
address.setCity("Delhi")
address.setCountry("India")
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you need to change a variable or set it permanently?

- A good example if it is something like **val pi5places = 3.14159** you would set it as `val`. Is there a possibility that you need to change that variable now or later, then you would set it as var.
- **For example :** The color of a car, can be `var colorCar = green`. Later you can change that `colorCar = blue`, where as a `val`, you can not.
- Responses here regarding `mutable` and `immutable` is fine, but may be scary if these terms are not well known or just getting into learning how to program.

Answer (score 3):

Both variables are used as initialising

- val like a constant variable, It can be readable, and the properties of a val can be modified.
- var just like a mutable variable. you can change the value at any time.

Answer (score 2):

**Var** means **Variable**-If you stored any object using **'var'** it could change in time.

For example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var a=12
    var b=13
    var c=12
    a=c+b **//new object 25**
    print(a)
}
```

**Val** means **value**-It's like a **'constant'** in java .if you stored any object using 'val' it could not change in time.

For Example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a=12
    var b=13
    var c=12
    a=c+b **//You can't assign like that.it's an error.**
    print(a)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Var** is a mutable variable. It is a variable that can be changed to another value. It's similar to declaring a variable in Java.

**Val** is a read-only thing. It's similar to **final** in java. A val must be initialized when it is created. This is because it cannot be changed after it is created.

```
var test1Var = "Hello"
println(test1Var)
test1Var = "GoodBye"
println(test1Var)
val test2Val = "FinalTestForVal";
println(test2Val);
```

Answer (score 1):

Both, `val` and `var` can be used for declaring variables (local and class properties).

**Local variables**:

1. `val` declares **read-only** variables that can only be assigned once, but *cannot be reassigned*.

Example:

```
val readonlyString = “hello”
readonlyString = “c u” // Not allowed for `val`
```

2. `var` declares *reassignable* variables as you know them from Java (the keyword will be introduced in Java 10, [“local variable type inference”](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286)).

Example:

```
var reasignableString = “hello”
reasignableString = “c u” // OK
```

*It is always preferable to use `val`. Try to avoid `var` as often as possible!*

**Class properties**:

Both keywords are also used in order to define [properties inside classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#properties-and-fields). As an example, have a look at the following `data class`:

```
data class Person (val name: String, var age: Int)
```

The `Person` contains two fields, one of which is readonly (`name`). The `age`, on the other hand, may be reassigned after class instantiation, via the provided `setter`. Note that `name` won’t have a corresponding setter method.

Answer (score 1):

`val` (from value):
Immutable reference. A variable declared with `val` can’t be
reassigned after it’s initialized. It corresponds to a `final` variable in Java.

`var` (from variable):
Mutable reference. The value of such a variable can be changed.
This declaration corresponds to a regular (non-final) Java variable.

Answer (score 1):

`val` like `constant` variable, itself cannot be changed, only can be read, but the properties of a `val` can be modified;
`var` just like mutant variable in other programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

VAR is used for creating those variable whose value will change over the course of time in your application. It is same as VAR of swift, whereas VAL is used for creating those variable whose value will not change over the course of time in your application.It is same as LET of swift.

Answer (score 1):

In short, **val** variable is final (not mutable) or constant value that won't be changed in future 
and 
**var** variable (mutable) can be changed in future.

```
class DeliveryOrderEvent(val d : Delivery)
// Only getter
```

See the above code. It is a model class, will be used for data passing. I have set **val** before the variable because this variable was used to get the data.

```
class DeliveryOrderEvent(var d : Delivery)

// setter and getter is fine here. No error
```

Also, if you need to set data later you need to use **var** keyword before a variable, if you only need to get the value once then use **val** keyword

Answer (score 0):

val - Immutable(once initialized can't be reassigned)

var - Mutable(can able to change value)

Example

in Kotlin -  val n = 20 & var n = 20

In Java  - final int n = 20; & int n = 20;

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin we use `var` to declare a **variable**. It is **mutable**. We **can** change, **reassign** variables. Example,

```
fun main(args : Array<String>){
    var x = 10
    println(x)

    x = 100 // vars can reassign.
    println(x)
}
```

We use val to declare **constants**. They are **immutable**. **Unable** to change, **reassign** vals. `val` is something similar to `final` variables in java. Example,

```
fun main(args : Array<String>){
    val y = 10
    println(y)

    y = 100 // vals can't reassign (COMPILE ERROR!).
    println(y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the exact answer from [de-compiling Kotlin to Java](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/yet-another-kotlin-vs-java-comparison).

If you do this in Kotlin:

```
data class UsingVarAndNoInit(var name: String)
data class UsingValAndNoInit(val name: String)
```

You will get **UsingVarAndNoInit**:

```
package classesiiiandiiiobjects.dataiiiclasses.p04variiiandiiival;

import kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public final class UsingVarAndNoInit {
  @NotNull private String name;

  @NotNull
  public final String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public final void setName(@NotNull String string) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull((Object) string, (String) "<set-?>");
    this.name = string;
  }

  public UsingVarAndNoInit(@NotNull String name) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull((Object) name, (String) "name");
    this.name = name;
  }

  @NotNull
  public final String component1() {
    return this.name;
  }

  @NotNull
  public final UsingVarAndNoInit copy(@NotNull String name) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull((Object) name, (String) "name");
    return new UsingVarAndNoInit(name);
  }

  @NotNull
  public static /* bridge */ /* synthetic */ UsingVarAndNoInit copy$default(
      UsingVarAndNoInit usingVarAndNoInit, String string, int n, Object object) {
    if ((n & 1) != 0) {
      string = usingVarAndNoInit.name;
    }
    return usingVarAndNoInit.copy(string);
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "UsingVarAndNoInit(name=" + this.name + ")";
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    String string = this.name;
    return string != null ? string.hashCode() : 0;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object object) {
    block3:
    {
      block2:
      {
        if (this == object) break block2;
        if (!(object instanceof UsingVarAndNoInit)) break block3;
        UsingVarAndNoInit usingVarAndNoInit = (UsingVarAndNoInit) object;
        if (!Intrinsics.areEqual((Object) this.name, (Object) usingVarAndNoInit.name)) break block3;
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

You will also get **UsingValAndNoInit**:

```
package classesiiiandiiiobjects.dataiiiclasses.p04variiiandiiival;

import kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public final class UsingValAndNoInit {
  @NotNull private final String name;

  @NotNull
  public final String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public UsingValAndNoInit(@NotNull String name) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull((Object) name, (String) "name");
    this.name = name;
  }

  @NotNull
  public final String component1() {
    return this.name;
  }

  @NotNull
  public final UsingValAndNoInit copy(@NotNull String name) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull((Object) name, (String) "name");
    return new UsingValAndNoInit(name);
  }

  @NotNull
  public static /* bridge */ /* synthetic */ UsingValAndNoInit copy$default(
      UsingValAndNoInit usingValAndNoInit, String string, int n, Object object) {
    if ((n & 1) != 0) {
      string = usingValAndNoInit.name;
    }
    return usingValAndNoInit.copy(string);
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "UsingValAndNoInit(name=" + this.name + ")";
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    String string = this.name;
    return string != null ? string.hashCode() : 0;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object object) {
    block3:
    {
      block2:
      {
        if (this == object) break block2;
        if (!(object instanceof UsingValAndNoInit)) break block3;
        UsingValAndNoInit usingValAndNoInit = (UsingValAndNoInit) object;
        if (!Intrinsics.areEqual((Object) this.name, (Object) usingValAndNoInit.name)) break block3;
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

There are more examples here: https://github.com/tomasbjerre/yet-another-kotlin-vs-java-comparison

Answer (score 0):

Normal

- `Val` is using for `static` field like in Java as `Static Keyword`
- Like `Static` in Java/ Same as in kotlin
- And `Var` denotes Variable Field in Kotlin that, you can change it.
- Mostly `Static` is used when you want to save value in static memory at once,

Example:

```
 if you assign

 val a=1
 a=3  You can not change it
```

- You can not change, this is final value and Static

  `var b=2`

  `b=4`  U can change it

Comment: This is completely wrong.  Ignoring the capitalization issues, this completely misunderstands the `static` keyword in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but there's one difference that I haven't seen mentioned. You can use `val` to assign a local variable in a `when` expression, but trying to use `var` will produce a compiler error:

```kotlin
sealed class Token {
    data class StringToken(val value: String) : Token()
    data class BoolToken(val value: Boolean) : Token()
}

fun getToken() : Token = Token.BoolToken(true)

val output = when (val token = getToken()) {
    is Token.StringToken -> token.value
    is Token.BoolToken -> token.value.toString()
}
```

This allows you to get access to the correctly type-inferred value in the expressions on the right.

Answer (score 0):

We use `var` to declare **variables** and
we use `val` to create **constants** which in java are preceded by the reserved word `final`

Answer (score -2):

```
fun copyAddress(address: Address): Address {
    val result = Address() // there's no 'new' keyword in Kotlin
    result.name = address.name // accessors are called
    **result = Address() // This is not possible because its **val****
    return result
}

fun copyAddress(address: Address): Address {
    var result = Address() // there's no 'new' keyword in Kotlin
    result.name = address.name // accessors are called
    **result = Address() // This is possible because its **var****
    return result
}
```

You can re-initialize an object when its var, but not when its val.
Using property is different, property has its own access specifiers and getter methods defined. Which determines the behavior's.
Please let me know if its not clarified!!

Answer (score -13):

var is a variable like any other language.
eg.

```
var price: Double
```

On the other side, val provides you feature of referencing.
eg.

```
val CONTINENTS = 7
// You refer this to get constant value 7. In this case, val acts as access
// specifier final in Java
```

and,

```
val Int.absolute: Int
    get() {
        return Math.abs(this)
    }
// You refer to the newly create 'method' which provides absolute value 
// of your integer

println(-5.absolute) // O.P: 5
```