# Why Kotlin uses the word "val" to stand for constant?

Tags: kotlin

I really want to know why Kotlin use the word `val` to stand for constant?

If `var` means variable.`val` means what ? `val` means `var` + `l` or `val` is only one word for short?

In the Kotlin Documentation,we only have the following words.

> Read-only local variables are declared using val keyword. Mutable
>   local variables are declared using var keyword.

This question is not only to make sense of the word `val`，but also Remind the WORD MAKER to tell us why they name the word,this is not a little thing,this will make us more comfortable to learn the new knowledge,we want to learn and make sense of everything.

For example,many people want to know why Swift use the word `let` or Why Objective-C use the `.m` filename extension?

**I think the official documentation or response is really important,any guess or assuming is not really helpful,because it's not convictive,the confused will be still the confused.**

I also asked this question in the official forum:
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/why-kotlin-use-the-word-val-to-stand-for-constant/4491

Some references:
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/change-val-to-something-else/1180/13

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44200189/5039950

Comment: If you are asking for official explanation. [Kotlin forum](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/) may be  a more suitable place to ask.

Comment: OK,I will try it later.Thank you for you help!

Comment: They might've taken those keywords from Scala since Scala uses them the same way.

Comment: Yeah,this is a good guess.Just now I have found this:https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/change-val-to-something-else/1180/13 Someone mentioned Scala

Comment: I believe it stands for `value`, and it is chosen because it just like `var`.

Answer (score 10):

`val` means `value`

This is a read-only value.

`var` is a mutable value

`const` would on the other hand be not 100% correct. The value PI (3.14..) is a constant. Its value never changes. The value of `x` in this line `val x = random.nextInt()` will (hopefully) always be different, but you want the value not to be modified in the function. So the keyword `val` is quite appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

`val` keyword is only one word. abbreviation for `val` not found anywhere. Your question explains what is `val`.

> Read-only local variables are declared using val keyword. Mutable
>   local variables are declared using var keyword.

Here is a site explains why `val` is Read-only and not immutable.

http://blog.danlew.net/2017/05/30/mutable-vals-in-kotlin/

> val does not mean immutable, val means read-only. That means that
>   you're not allowed to explicitly write to a val, but it doesn't
>   guarantee that they're immutable

https://artemzin.com/blog/kotlin-val-does-not-mean-immutable-it-just-means-readonly-yeah/

> Kotlin allows you declare get() of the val which breaks immutability
>   of the property and leaves only read permission for external "users".

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin's syntax is inspired by Scala. In Kotlin several ideas are taken from Scala besides the syntax. Kotlin also adds things on its own and does certain things very differently than Scala (i.e., no implicit conversion in Kotlin compared to Scala). Long matter short: You have to ask the Scala guys why they chose the keyword combination var and val.

Answer (score 1):

- `val` from value.
- `var` from variable.
- `value` - a property such as number assigned to or calculated for a **variable, constant or expression(wiki)**
- `variable` - a symbolic name associated with a `value` and **whose associated value may be changed(wiki)**