# PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "expenses" violates foreign key constraint "expenses_user_id_fkey"

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I am working on simple Spring Boot service with Kotlin, and PostgreSql. I use JPA. Currently I have two tables "users", and "expenses", "expenses" table have reference to "users" id:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE expenses (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id),
    price DECIMAL NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR
);
```

Entities look like this:

```
@Entity
data class Users (
        @Id @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO ) val id: 
Long,
        val username: String,
        var password: String
) {
    @OneToMany
    val expenses: MutableSet<Expenses> = HashSet()
}

@Entity
data class Expenses(
        @Id @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO ) val id: 
Long? = null,
        val user_id: Long,
        val price: BigDecimal? = null,
        val title: String? = null,
        val description: String? = null
) {
    @ManyToOne
    lateinit var users: Users

    constructor(user_id: Long, users: Users) : this(user_id = user_id) {
        this.users = users
    }
}
```

I use JPA repository to connect to database, and CrudRepository to insert data into database:

```
interface ExpensesRepository : CrudRepository<Expenses, Long> {
}
```

Heres the code I use for inserting data into db:

```
@PostMapping("/expenses")
@ResponseBody
fun insertExpense(@RequestBody expenses: Expenses): Expenses {
    expensesRepository.save(expenses);
    return expenses;
}
```

And JSON I send to "/expenses" with method post:

```
{
    "user_id:": 43,
    "price": 10.99,
    "title": "C++ course",
    "description": "One time pay"
}
```

And service throws PSQLException:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "expenses" violates foreign key constraint "expenses_user_id_fkey"
  Detail: Key (user_id)=(0) is not present in table "users".
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2477) ~[postgresql-42.1.4.jar:42.1.4]
...
```

There is some answers in stackoverflow with the same error, bug technology stack are different.

I use gradle.
Java version: 1.8
Kotlin version: 1.2.51
Spring Boot version: 2.0.6.RELEASE
PostgreSql version: 9.5.10
PostgreSql driver version: 42.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting the object of user in your expenses object. The relationship seems to be broken as in the error you are getting  Key (user_id)=(0) not (43) which is the number you entered. Try below solution.
https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-data/kotlin-springjpa-hibernate-one-many-relationship

```
@Entity
data class Users (
        @Id @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO ) val id: 
Long,
        val username: String,
        var password: String
) {
    @OneToMany
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "users", cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL), fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    val expenses: MutableSet<Expenses> = HashSet()
}

@Entity
data class Expenses(
        @Id @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO ) val id: 
Long? = null,
        val user_id: Long,
        val price: BigDecimal? = null,
        val title: String? = null,
        val description: String? = null
) {
    @ManyToOne
    lateinit var users: Users
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    constructor(user_id: Long, users: Users) : this(user_id = user_id) {
        this.users = users
    }
}
```

From user_id you are putting in input, you can first find the user and then set the user object in the expenses and then try to save it.

Comment: Hi thank you for helping! The link you . provided helped me :) Problem was in `val`. I changed from `val` to `var`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44200189/5834613) says that `val` is same as final in Java