# How can you change the value of a mutable list/map/array when its defined as a val type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mutable

I'm new to Kotlin and I've been reading a lot about how `val` is read-only and `var` is mutable. That's fine i get it. But what's confusing is when you create a mutable lsit/map/array and you've assigned it as a `val`, how is it allowed to be mutable? Doesn't that change the read-only aspect of `val` properties/variables/objects?

Comment: You may want to see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200075/val-and-var-in-kotlin

Comment: @mrossini I did but I felt that didn't help me understand properly

Comment: The `val` prevents reassigning, but it doesn't prevent modification. For example, by writing `val list: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()`, you say that `list` will always contain the same list, which still can be modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyObject {
    val a = mutableListOf<String>()
}
```

means that the field for `a` is final, and there is no setter for `a`.

You thus can't do

```
myObject.a = anotherList
```

It says nothing about the mutability of the list itself. Since the list is mutable, you can do

```
myObject.a.add("foo")
```

Comment: This makes it seems like it was so simple to begin with i don't know why I didn't get it! Thanks!