# Why can a val variable be assigned data in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The following code is from the project [play-billing-samples](http://%20https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples.git).

`private val repository` is `val`, why can `repository = BillingRepository.getInstance(application)` work well?

In my mind, a val must be initialize at definition , such as `private val repository: BillingRepository by lazy {BillingRepository.getInstance(application)}` .

**Code**

```
class BillingViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val gasTankLiveData: LiveData<GasTank>
    val premiumCarLiveData: LiveData<PremiumCar>
    val goldStatusLiveData: LiveData<GoldStatus>
    val subsSkuDetailsListLiveData: LiveData<List<AugmentedSkuDetails>>
    val inappSkuDetailsListLiveData: LiveData<List<AugmentedSkuDetails>>

    private val LOG_TAG = "BillingViewModel"
    private val viewModelScope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.Main)
    private val repository: BillingRepository

    init {
        repository = BillingRepository.getInstance(application)
        repository.startDataSourceConnections()
        gasTankLiveData = repository.gasTankLiveData
        premiumCarLiveData = repository.premiumCarLiveData
        goldStatusLiveData = repository.goldStatusLiveData
        subsSkuDetailsListLiveData = repository.subsSkuDetailsListLiveData
        inappSkuDetailsListLiveData = repository.inappSkuDetailsListLiveData
    }

...
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44361695/7666442

Comment: val must be initialized once and never be changed. It is causing no issue because you are initializing it inside init {}, as soon as BillingViewModel is initialized repository is initialized as well. If you move repository initialization out of init{} it will give an error.

Comment: val should be initialized only once. Either directly or inside constructor . Its a similar concept as `blank final variable in java`.

Answer (score 0):

For purposes of initializing `val` variables, the declaration line, any initializer blocks (the `init { ... }` blocks), and the constructor are equivalent to initializing at the point of definition, because they are all run before the object is considered properly constructed.

Any `val` variables must be initialized exactly once in the combination of the declaration, all initializer blocks, and the constructor.