# val or var when creating objects in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have seen some tutorials use val when creating an instance of class and some use var. I understand how val and var are different when declaring variables. However, I could not understand when we should use var and when should we use val when creating objects?

Comment: Its the same thing for objects but in terms of the ability to assign different object to the instance. You can change the object using setters but cant reassign to a different one in case you use val.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between var and val in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200075/what-is-the-difference-between-var-and-val-in-kotlin)

Comment: Because of design of your code, and make less mistakes

Answer (score 1):

A *property* is just some value associated with an object:

```
class MyClass {
    var someProperty: String = "wow"
}
```

If it's a `val` it's *read-only* and can't be changed. If it's a `var` then you can set a different value on that property later.

---

You can initialise properties based on parameters passed into the constructor:

```
class Rectangle(width: Int, height: Int) {
    val width: Int = width
    val height: Int = height
    val area: Int = width * height
}
```

But instead of creating properties and copying their values from the constructor parameters like that, Kotlin lets you take a shortcut. [You can make those constructor parameters into properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors) just by adding the `val` or `var` keyword:

```
class Rectangle(val width: Int, val height: Int) {
    val area: Int = width * height
}
```

It's basically the same code as before, just shorter! The `area` property is still defined inside the class, because it's *not* a value that should be passed in as a parameter - it's a value that's derived from the two that the caller *does* provide.

---

So now you know that you basically *are* creating a variable here, hopefully it's more obvious whether you should use `val` or `var` - does the variable need to be changeable? If so, you need a `var`. If not, always default to `val`. Whether you're defining the variable in a function, in the top level of a class, or as a property in the constructor, it's all the same thing